# Jquery Mobile ListView Image cause input and select not working

Tags: android, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

All:

I'm use Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap to build app now.
I got a strange issue with recently
the image in listview cause the select not work
look the screen-shot
anybody can help me?

[image]

this issue occur on android 2.x
android4.x and ios works fine

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the reason.
I'm using jquery-mobile-1.3.1 and phonegap-2.9.0
the following code cause this issue. comment it works fine.

```
.ui-android-2x-fixed .ui-li-has-thumb {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```